# Asesinado vs. fallecido

Tags: significado

Quisiera confirmar si "el resultado" de "asesinado"y "el resultado" de "fallecido" son lo mismo. Según este [enlace](https://es.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Asesinato_de_Carlos_Palomino), parece que no. Muchas gracias ~

"Los colectivos antifascistas colocaron hasta en cuatro ocasiones placas en las bocas de Metro donde había fallecido Carlos Palomino, pero siempre eran vandalizadas. En 2016, el Ayuntamiento de Madrid colocó una placa en el número 145 del Paseo de las Delicias, lugar donde Palomino fue asesinado".

O sea, "fallecido en las bocas de Metro" y "asesinado en el número 145 del Paseo de las Delicias", que son 2 lugares diferentes.

Comment: Asesinado y fallecido es igual en tu idioma?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

En tu cita es posible usar ambos términos indiferentemente. Si alguien fue asesinado, entonces falleció y está muerto. La implicación recíproca no es válida, y por lo tanto los términos no son sinónimos.

El término más general es **morir**, de donde salen otros términos derivados. En tu caso:

**Asesinar** significa ‘quitar la vida de modo premeditado, con alevosía, ensañamiento y otros agravantes’ [Wikcionario]. En otras palabras, quiere decir: matar a alguien en forma planificada.

**Fallecer** hace referencia a una muerte ‘técnica’, es el ‘finar de lo vivo’. Este término se usa como reemplazo de *morir*: en ámbitos científicos, cuando se obtiene suficiente evidencia empírica de que un ser vivo ya no presenta signos de vida; o bien en ámbitos jurídicos, cuando se declara legalmente a una persona como ‘fallecida’, es decir que técnicamente ya no está presente.

> O sea, "fallecido en las bocas de Metro" y "asesinado en el número 145 del Paseo de las Delicias", que son 2 lugares diferentes.

No, es el mismo lugar. ‘Paseo de las Delicias 145’ es la dirección en donde se encuentra la  entrada al metro, o por lo menos está muy cerca.

Comment: ¡Muchísimas gracias por su respuesta, tac! Tengo una pregunta. ... ¿Por qué "el resultado" de "asesinado"y "el resultado" de "fallecido" tomaron lugar en dos sitios diferentes, según el enlace? Muchas gracias otra vez!

Comment: @Maurice es el mismo lugar. Las bocas del metro es el lugar de la calle donde bajás a la estación. Y está en esa dirección. [En esta noticia](https://www.abc.es/espana/madrid/abci-carmena-pondra-placa-carlos-palomino-menor-antifascista-asesinado-neonazi-201605121119_noticia.html) mencionan que una vez pusieron una placa en Paseo de las Delicias 132 pero fue destrozada. Quizá estaba muy al alcance del peatón, entonces ahora pusieron una en Paseo de las Delicias 145.

Comment: @Maurice si querés más precisión, cambiá ‘aquí falleció Palomino’ por ‘acá falleció Palonimo’

Comment: Ah ~ ¡Muchísimas gracias de verdad por su ayuda, tac!

Comment: No entiendo el comentario de la precisión. Y menos cuando hablamos de un hecho acontecido en España, donde predomina el uso de "aquí" frente a "acá".

Comment: @RubioRic ‘aquí’ denota un lugar preciso, por decirlo de algùn modo pensalo de esta forma: un punto (x,y,z) en el espacio. ‘acá’ significa ‘en este lugar’ en forma imprecisa. Si tuvieron que correr la placa unos metros del lugar exacto en donde murió entonces sería ‘acá’ en lugar de ‘aquí’. LA precisión del ‘este lugar’ es menor, pero en este caso es mayor la exactitud en el discurso. *Capito*?

Comment: @RubioRic Ah, y se me olvidó una aclaración que no es menos importante. En la Argentina no se dice ‘aquí’. Se usa ‘acá’ indiferentemente, pudiendo tener cualquiera de los dos sentidos mencionados. Por lo tanto, desconozco el límite de lo preciso e impreciso pero introducí el término para que Maurice comprenda que en realidad es (y no es) el mismo lugar

Comment: Despues de tus comentarios me quedo igual. "Aquí" y "acá" no tienen nada que ver con la pregunta original y añaden un nivel más de confusión al que ya tenía el OP, aún más si "acá" se usa indistintamente en Argentina.

Comment: Carlos Palomino fue apuñalado dentro de un vagón del metro, sus amigos lo extrajeron de ahí hasta fuera de la estación del metro, donde se dictaminó el fallecimiento. Es decir, fue asesinado en el metro, donde recibió la puñalada que acabaría con su vida, pero falleció, como consecuencia del hecho, fuera de la parada.

Comment: @RubioRic Leyendo entre líneas, la pregunta de Maurice tiene que ver con que si la placa la colocaron en el mismo lugar en donde lo asesinaron. Respuesta: Sí, siempre y cuando se entienda en el sentido de un ‘acá’. No es *exactamente* el mismo lugar, pero lo entendemos válido en un sentido laxo. Creo que lo que te confunde probablementre sea que a nivel pragmático ‘acá’ y ‘fue asesinado’ no se lleven bien. Insisto: pedí prestado el término sólo para que entendiera